# Integrating Azure OpenAI with ServiceNow: 404 Error on API Request

Tags: azure, servicenow, azure-openai

We're attempting to integrate Azure OpenAI's GPT-4.0-turbo model with our ServiceNow instance. Our goal is to test AI functionalities within our environment. We have obtained an API token and endpoint from Azure, and our Azure contact has whitelisted our instance's IP address.

Despite this setup, we're encountering a persistent issue. Our ServiceNow script, intended to make a POST request to the OpenAI API, consistently returns a 404 error, indicating that the resource cannot be found.

Here's the relevant part of our script: (endpoint and token are removed for security)

```
var openaiApiUrl = 'https://**********.openai.azure.com/'; // Replace with your OpenAI endpoint URL
var openaiApiKey = 'b060f***************7d7e570e'; // Replace with your OpenAI API key

// Prepare the request body
var requestBody = {
    "model": "gpt-4.0-turbo", // Specify the model
    "messages": [ // Add your messages here
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."
        }
    ]
};
var requestBodyString = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

// Create and configure the HTTP request
var httpRequest = new GlideHTTPRequest(openaiApiUrl);
httpRequest.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httpRequest.addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + openaiApiKey);

// Send the request and handle the response
var response = httpRequest.post(requestBodyString);

// Log the response for debugging
gs.info("Status Code: " + response.getStatusCode());
gs.info("Response Body: " + response.getBody());
```

The response we receive is:
Status Code: 404
Response Body: {"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}

We're seeking guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please look at the REST API documentation here for chat completions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#chat-completions.

Comment: Check that the "model" name in your request body is the deployment name in your azure open AI resource.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it like this:

```
var resourceName = '****-open-ai-it-sn'; // *** is for security reason 
var deploymentName = '****-Open-AI-IT-SN-gpt4'; // *** is for security reason 
var apiKey = '50ebb8*******bbbfc495b7ecd'; 


var restMessage = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
restMessage.setHttpMethod('post');
restMessage.setEndpoint('https://' + resourceName + '.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/' + deploymentName + '/chat/completions?api-version=2023-07-01-preview');
restMessage.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
restMessage.setRequestHeader('api-key', apiKey);


var requestBody = {
messages: [
{ role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
{ role: 'user', content: 'What is Examination in norwegian?' },

]
};
restMessage.setRequestBody(JSON.stringify(requestBody));


var response = restMessage.execute();
var responseBody = response.getBody();
gs.info(responseBody);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**